# Importing Excel-tables in R

Tags: r, excel, openxlsx

Is there a way to import a named Excel-table into R as a data.frame?

I typically have several named Excel-tables on a single worksheet, that I want to import as data.frames, without relying on static row - and column references for the location of the Excel-tables.

I have tried to set `namedRegion` which is an available argument for several Excel-import functions, but that does not seem to work for named Excel-tables. I am currently using the openxlxs package, which has a function `getTables()` that creates a variable with Excel-table names from a single worksheet, but not the data in the tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get your named table is a little bit of work.

First you need to load the workbook.

```
library(openxlsx)

wb <- loadWorkbook("name_excel_file.xlsx")
```

Next you need to extract the name of your named table.

```
# get the name and the range
tables <- getTables(wb = wb,
                    sheet = 1)
```

If you have multiple named tables they are all in `tables`. My named table is called **Table1**.

Next you to extract the column numbers and row numbers, which you will later use to extract the named table from the Excel file.

```
# get the range
table_range <- names(tables[tables == "Table1"])
table_range_refs <- strsplit(table_range, ":")[[1]]

# use a regex to extract out the row numbers
table_range_row_num <- gsub("[^0-9.]", "", table_range_refs)
# extract out the column numbers
table_range_col_num <- convertFromExcelRef(table_range_refs)
```

Now you re-read the Excel file with the `cols` and `rows` parameter.

```
# finally read it
my_df <- read.xlsx(xlsxFile = "name_excel_file.xlsx",
                   sheet = 1,
                   cols = table_range_col_num[1]:table_range_col_num[2],
                   rows = table_range_row_num[1]:table_range_row_num[2])
```

You end up with a data frame with only the content of your named table.

I used this a while ago. I found this code somewhere, but I don't know anymore from where.

Comment: Thanks I will def. try this. :)

Answer (score 1):

This link is might be useful for you

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17709204/10235327

```
1. Install XLConnect package
2. Save a path to your file in a variable
3. Load workbook
4. Save your data to df
```

To get table names you can use function

```
getTables(wb,sheet=1,simplify=T)
```

Where:

- wb - your workbook
- sheet - sheet name or might be the number as well
- simplify = TRUE (default) the result is simplified to a vector

https://rdrr.io/cran/XLConnect/man/getTables-methods.html

Here's the code (not mine, copied from the topic above, just a bit modified)

```
require(XLConnect)
sampleFile = "C:/Users/your.name/Documents/test.xlsx"
wb = loadWorkbook(sampleFile)
myTable <- getTables(wb,sheet=1)
df<-readTable(wb, sheet = 1, table = myTable)
```

Comment: Thanks, this does solve my issue although XLConnect package relies on Java, which we are not allowed to install on company PCs. :/

Comment: You're welcome! Yes, all these 'not allowed to install' relates to my work as well :) But, maybe they can provide you with remote PC where it is possible to use java.

Answer (score 0):

You can check next packages:

```
library(xlsx)
Data <- read.xlsx('YourFile.xlsx',sheet=1)

library(readxl)
Data <- read_excel('YourFile.xlsx',sheet=1)
```

Both options allow you to define specific regions to load the data into `R`.

Answer (score 0):

I use `read.xlsx` from package `openxlsx`. For example:

```
library(openxlsx)
fileA <- paste0(some.directory,'excel.file.xlsx')
A <-  read.xlsx(fileA, startRow = 3)
```

hope it helps

Comment: This is what I am doing now. But this is not addressing the issue of named tables in Excel.